# Can't use drivers for GPU - Sapphire R9 270X 2GB Dual-X OC in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, steam, amd-graphics

I'm a new user to Ubuntu OS.

I get it 1 month ago and since I have it seems like it doesn't work really good and sometimes and some little freeze or just the animation isn't good like it must be. When I installed Steam and played some games I saw that the Framerate wasn't good as before when I run Windows 10 on my pc.

I thought that I didn't installed any Drivers on Ubuntu so I started to search if I can still download the driver for Ubuntu. By the AMD website, I saw there are some drivers, but for the version Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, 14.04.2

I have 18.04 so isn't any way to get some driver and play with a normal Framerate or just make it better?

Comment: @Dave PPA don't really work... I done as you said but I didin't saw something get better. And when I checked for DRI3 I had an error by the _cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log_ . And I can't try by going to AMD Drivers website cause the Drivers for my GPU are compatible with **Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, 14.04.2** and not with 18.04. I even have low Framerate even when I click to the 9 Little dots for "Show Application", the animation goes so slowly and with low framerate... thats my spec if maybe it can help you more. CPU-AMD Athlon X4 860K Quad Core Processor 3.70 GHz 
GPU-Sapphire R9 270X 2GB Dual-X OC

Comment: Did you add the lines to your "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" file? If you didn't, then it will throw an error. The DRI3 is what will increase graphical performance. As far as the actual AMD drivers, you need to download the drivers from that web address I supplied. Those drivers should work if you get them from there, they should work.

Comment: @Dave I did but still it didin’t worked, I will try another time at next week then I will let you know :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to install drivers for the AMD GPU:
  AMD Radeon HD Series Drivers
OR
  OPEN SOURCE (Currently Recommended)

First:

AMD Radeon HD Series Drivers

In order to get the drivers, you need to go to the AMD Download Page: [ADM Drivers and Support](https://www.amd.com/en/support) and grab the latest version of the drivers that matches your card. The release should come in the form of a tarball. Either extract the tarball automatically with your GUI archive manager through your browser or let it download and extract it using "tar" from the command line:

```
tar -xJvf amdgpu-pro_*.tar.xz
```

A directory containing all of the necessary packages will be created based on the version of the drivers. Go into that directory:

```
cd amdgpu-pro-XX.XX-XXXXXX
```

Don't worry about installing all of those packages individually. There's an installer script that will handle everything for you. Run the script as a regular user. It will ask you for your password to use "sudo". If you want to be lazy, add the "-y" flag to answer "Yes" to every question, like this:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

Let the script run and install all of your packages. It'll take a bit of time, but once it's done, your system will be ready. Just restart, and you can start using your new drivers.

Uninstalling the AMDGPU Graphics Stack

To remove all components of the stack, run the uninstall script from anywhere in the system. Based on whether you installed the All-Open or Pro components, run one of the following commands:

Use this for All-Open components:

```
amdgpu-uninstall
```

Use this for Pro components:

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

After uninstalling the components, reboot the system.
That was for the AMD Radeon HD Series Drivers.

Now for OPEN SOURCE (Currently Recommended):

If you're running Ubuntu 18.04, you already have the open source AMD drivers installed. They're integrated into Mesa and the Linux kernel. Since, Ubuntu 18.04 is new, it'll have some of the latest features. However, if you want the absolute latest as long as you're running your system, there's an excellent PPA that packages Git versions of Mesa.

Add The PPA

This PPA also includes the Gallium Nine patches which enable DirectX9 support for Mesa. You can use it along with Wine to play older Windows games with near native performance. Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

After you've added the PPA, update Apt, and run a full upgrade:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Apt will automatically pull in the updated packages from the PPA.

ENABLE DRI3

DRI3 will increase graphical performance with the AMDGPU drivers. In order to enable it, you need to add a few lines to your "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" file. Open it with "sudo" using your favorite text editor.

If it does not exist, you will need to create it. Navigate to /etc/ and open the "X11" folder as administrator by right clicking on it and selecting "Open as Administrator" and enter password to authenticate. Create new document and name it "xorg.config". Now copy:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMDGPU"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

Paste to the newly created or existing /xorg.config and save.

Once you've added that. Save, and restart your computer. When it reboots, you'll be using the latest version of Mesa with DRI3 enabled. To verify if DRI3 is enabled, run:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep DRI3
```

You should get something similar to this if it is:

```
[    10.039] (**) RADEON(0): DRI3 enabled
```

=== Revert to original drivers ===

To revert to standard Ubuntu drivers type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

(IF YOU DON"T HAVE IT)

Next:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

More info: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

My opinion is that the OPEN SOURCE seemed to work better, but they are updated way more frequently. The AMD Radeon HD Series Drivers seemed make my cpu run warmer.

Also, a footnote, DRI3 can be enabled with the already installed Ubuntu 18.04 open source AMD drivers by following the guide above: ENABLE DR13

If you want to verify direct rendering, perform these steps:

Verify that direct rendering is enabled:

```
glxinfo | grep direct
```

You should get something like this:

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_direct_state_access, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
```

Ensure that 3-D applications work, run this:

```
glxgears
```

If the gears run, then your PC is configured.

Whichever drivers you choose, your graphics card should perform well.